# Regular Expression to match U.S. Cities allowing certain special characters

Tags: regex, validation

I am working on a regualar expression to check for a valid U.S. city name. My requirements are as follows:

- Can only be 25 characters
- Can only accept alpha characters and the following special characters: `',.-`.
- Should evaluate **false** using: `St. Clou$$, Prai!@rie, $t. Thomas`.
- Should evaluate **true** using: `O'John, St. Cloud, Cov d'Aline, Milt-Freeman`.

Here is the expression I have so far:
`/(^|\s)[a-zA-Z',.\s-]{1,25}(?=\s|$)((?!\W)[a-zA-Z',.\s-]{1,25}(?=\s|$))?/g`

Here is how I have been testing:

```
let regex = /(^|\s)[a-zA-Z',.-\s]{1,25}(?=\s|$)((?!\W)[a-zA-Z',.-\s]{1,25}(?=\s|$))?/g;
let str = "St. Clou$$";
let validation = regex.test(str)
if(validation){
    return true 
} else { 
    return false }
```

Using the test above, the regex expression seems to be passing all of the true conditions but my test is also returning `true` for `St. Clou$$` and `$t. Thomas`. It seems like when there are multiple words and one of the words has a unacceptable special character it still passes.

What can I add to make the expression return false for all false conditions mentioned above? Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: First - `-` has a special meaning in a character class (inside `[]`). Look it up ;) Second - the part `(^|\s)[a-zA-Z',.-\s]{1,25}(?=\s|$)` matches for example ` s `, or `   ` (three spaces) - or a single character `C`. The second part is optional (`((?!\W)[a-zA-Z',.-\s]{1,25}(?=\s|$))?`). So all the regex has to match to return true is one of the mentioned combination (for example). You should anchor the start and end of the string (using `^` and `$`).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I realized the `-` was in the wrong spot as soon as I posted. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
^[a-zA-Z',.\s-]{1,25}$
```

It matches 1-25 of your allowed characters, matching the start of the string `^` and end `$`. Also note that I placed the `-` at the end of the character class since it otherwise defines a range of characters.

Here's an illustrationusing JS:

```js
var re = /^[a-zA-Z',.\s-]{1,25}$/g,
    data = ['St. Clou$$', 'New York', 'Prai!@rie', 'Houston', '$t. Thomas', 'Chicago'];

data.forEach(function(city) {

  document.write(city + '=');

  if(re.test(city)) {
    document.write('true<br>');
  } else {
    document.write('false<br>');
  }
});
```

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/S0CPTc/1).